# Что вы думаете о возможности создания вычислимой (по Тьюринга) модели разума (сознания, души)?

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, алгоритм

Если возможна, будет ли эта модель "настоящей" душой (то есть требуется ли для "настоящести" биологический мозг)? Если нет, верите ли вы в возможность научного исследования и описания невычислимого разума?

Comment: Хм, а что вы подразумеваете под *вычислимой* моделью? Вычислимость по Тьюрингу - довольно строгое понятие, которое вводят для функций. А что такое вычислимая "модель" не очень-то и понятно.

Comment: математическая модель для описания состояния которой достаточно решений вычислимых задач, то есть не требуется решения невычислимых (в строгом смысле) задач (то есть задач, для которых решение есть, но нет алгоритма решения. Пример: можно ли заполнить плоскость заданным набором полимино - невычислимая задача, хотя для каждого набора существует решение, то есть либо можно заполнить, либо нельзя)

Comment: (Пусть будет по лямбда-исчислению, в определении большой разницы нет, так как невычислимая там будет невычислимой и там (ну ты понял;))

Comment: @asianirish В таком случае мне кажется, что это произойдет в том и только в том случае, когда появится математический способ **полностью** формализовать биохимические процессы (или взять какую-то их часть и доказать, что другие можно откинуть) в человеческом организме. С учетом того, что пока что многие из этих процессов просто не поддаются анализу, мне кажется, в ближайшие несколько десятков лет угрозы `SkyNet'a` не предвидится :)

Comment: меня больше интересует не практическая возможность при текущем уровне развития техники и знаний по биохимии, а принципиальная (логичиская, матиматическая) возможность при условии существования, например, компьютера с неограниченными ресурсами - памяти и скорости выполнения. По сути означает, что требует ли материя, из который состоит "материальный носитель" сознания отрицания ФИЗИЧЕСКОГО аспекта тезиса Чёрча — Тьюринга

Comment: Хм...создание души для нейронной сети? Звучит красиво, правда. Но не кажется ли вам, что душа, с точки зрения физики( если в нее добавить немного эзотерики ), это ни что иное, как энергия. Энергия человеческого тела, заключенная во внутреннем пространстве живого существа. При смерти эта энергия высвобождается, так как ей нечем "питаться" и возникает таким образом сущность, именуемая "душой". У махины, на которой будет функционировать нейросеть такой штуки нет....разве что разломать суперкомпьютер в процессе работы на нем этой самой нейронки...но это абсурд =)

Comment: Здорово, что такие вопросы вообще возникают.

Comment: В советской России не ты пишешь код, а код пишет тебя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верю.

*P.S. Аргументов нет, потому что категория верю/не верю не подразумевает аргументацию*

**Update**

Придется аргументировать раз такая пьянка пошла :)

Вопрос на самом то деле упирается не в `верю/не верю` в модель разума, а в `верю/не верю` в душу. А душа есть субстанция с которой оперирует Господь. То есть все упирается `в верю/не верю` в Бога. Если душу можно смоделировать машиной, значит Бога нет. Если нельзя значит Бог есть. Путем несложным логических выкладок теперь можно легко убедиться кто в этой дискуссии верит в Бога, а кто атеист.

Comment: все же хотелось бы развернутого мнения, это же не религиозная вера

Comment: ИМХО любой вопрос веры (не обязательно религиозной) не предполагает аргументации. Возможно, правильнее было бы поставить вопрос так: "Как вы думаете, возможно ли ...?" или что-то в этом роде.

Comment: Кстати,

[Какие вопросы не стоит задавать?](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8)

> Не стоит задавать вопросы-опросы, где каждый ответ является верным

> Не стоит задавать вопросы, предполагающие спорные и субъективные ответы.

Comment: спешу признать с улыбкой хмурой. но давайте уж закончим вопрос, пожалуйста, отмечу как "правильный" наиболее умный ответ

Comment: Barmaley, не все так просто. Невычислимость разума (то есть ответ "нет") подразумевает две возможности: 
1. потому что работа разума принципиально непознаваема и не поддается научным методам исследования, только мистическому пониманию
2. Материальный носитель разума работает на невычислимых (но познаваемых!) законов. По сути такой "материальный носитель" отрицает ФИЗИЧЕСКИЙ тезис Чёрча-Тьюринга, но вполне себе описыается математическим инструментом.
В (1) наверное да, подразумевается вера в Бога, в (2) - не факт, хотя возможна

Comment: Кстати, ответ "да" тоже оставляет место вере, например человек говорит: "да, вычислимая модель возможна, но это не настоящая душа, только модель, просто она ВЕДЕТ СЕБЯ как настоящая душа, но на самом деле ничего не чувствует и не понимает, и только мы, божьи создания, из плоти непостижимым и мистическим образом являемся носителями настоящей души"

Comment: Имхо, не надо обучать ИИ правильным реакциям. Достаточно ИИ с анализом опыта(поиск похожих цепей и упрощение их) и фильтрацией памяти (наиболее сильно "взволновавшее" откладывается в долговременную, оттуда в "генную", остальное выкидывается). При сбоях запускается новый процесс с генной памятью предыдущего. Алсо, в нейронную сеть можно запилить и звук, и вкус и тд, так что да, вполне возможно. 

ЗЫ: я совсем не атеист. Но т.к. для Всезнающего случайностей(aka "мера незнания") не существует -> разум появился не случайно -> его можно воссоздать =)

Comment: И да, единственное, что нужно этому ИИ - шкала радости; факторы, на нее влияющие(для начала можно тупо файлы удалять); способ взаимодействия со средой; и как можно больше хаоса. This is what I call self-education, baby :)

Comment: С математической точки зрения, вероятнее всего, что наш мир смоделировали, чем то, что он образовался случайно ( в том числе и человек). Так что можете добавить в апдейт это косвенное доказательство. 

Хочу так же добавить, что душа и разум понятия  разные, создание бездушного разума возможно, но это будет интеллект в чистом виде, без эмоций, только холодный расчет который не знает милосердия, ведь это нерационально. Создание ИИ притягивает меня и одновременно пугает, мы ходим по лезвию ножа.

Answer (score 3):

Мой ответ хоть и запоздалый, но, надеюсь, он более подробный, так как я длительное время занимаюсь темами ИИ и когнитивной науки.

Определимся с понятиями:

- Под интеллектом будем понимать способность обрабатывать информацию и приходить к какому-то решению. Без понимания, зачем это и почему. Тогда интеллектуальны в какой-то мере все вычислительные машины, хотя конечно, нейронная сеть будет более интеллектуальная, чем калькулятор. А оценивать интеллект можно по количеству обрабатываемой *разнородной информации* и способности к *обучению*.
- Сознание, разум — это сильный интеллект (т.е., способный обучаться обрабатывать новые виды информации), который обладает каким-либо пониманием себя и своего места в мире, своих целей. Не обязательно в физическом мире, можно представить операционную систему будущего, которая будет общаться с пользователем посредством человеческого языка и с другими компьютерами для достижения своих целей.

Таким образом, гипотетически можно построить искусственный разум, задать ему алгоритмы обучения, систему ценностей, даже эмоции, которые будут влиять на поведение. (Здесь уместно задаться вопросом, такой разум будет действительно чувствовать или только симулировать это? [Пища для размышлений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0).) Но будет ли этот созданный разум сопоставим с человеческим? Очевидно, что мы обладаем мощными способностями к пониманию и обучению. Значит, для аналогичных способностей нужна универсальная [система представления знаний](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) и такой же универсальный алгоритм обучения. Под словом "универсальный" я понимаю "сопоставимый с человеческим", потому как вполне могут быть иметь место интеллектуальные способности выше человеческих, но об этом чуть позже.

На искусственные нейронные сети с самого их создания регулярно возлагают слишком большие надежды. Которые не оправдываются. Стоит обратить внимание на тот факт, что ИНС не имеют вычислительной полноты. Подробнее об этом можно почитать [здесь](http://aideus.ru/?p=305). Также, у них совсем нет полноты представления знаний; сложно представить, как в ИНС будет храниться знание "Маша никогда не забывает чистить зубы перед сном".

Встают закономерные вопросы, а можно ли в принципе создать (1) систему представления знания  и (2) механизм обучения сопоставимый или выше человеческого? Здесь стоит указать, что я искренний христианин и считаю, что наше сознание не ограничено мозгом, а имеет также нематериальную природу.

1.
Наш мир дискретен (не будем принимать во внимание столь мало исследованную квантовую физику). Дискретно всё, камни, буквы, печеньки, молекулы, атомы. И, конечно же, байты с битами. При этом, сознание человека далеко не дискретно, в нём встречаются очень расплывчатые взаимосвязи и сочетания сущностей. Но вдохните воздух — несмотря на дискретность, он кажется очень не точечным. Потому, что состоит из множества маленьких частичек. Вероятно, наши компьютеры смогут аналогично интегрировать знания до множества различных, маленьких компонент. Это предполагает сложные алгоритмы и большие вычислительные ресурсы, но, в принципе, система представления знания сопоставимая с таковой в человеческом сознании возможна.

2.
Обучающиеся программы, машины способные заменить человека при решении удручающих интеллектуальных задач, всегда были мечтой энтузиастов. Некоторые даже фантазируют о самоулучшающемся ИИ, который будет создавать более интеллектуальный интеллект, а тот ещё более, и ещё, что приведёт к [технологической сингулярности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Но можно ли создать хотя бы человеческий интеллект? Здесь точных аргументов нет, но я считаю, что нельзя. Сколько учёные когнитивной психологии и другие не стараются описать фундаментальные принципы человеческого мышления и познания, почти столько же у них это не получается. Мы можем запрограммировать, а компьютеры выполнить только то, что мы можем понять и описать. Но мы не можем понять самих себя, как мы думаем и мыслим, а значит, не можем этого создать. Это *трансцендентность*. То есть, наше сознание основано на иных материях и процессах, чём-то вроде [гипервычислений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Из всего выше получается, что искусственный разум можно создать, можно сделать его приближенный к человеческим способностям, но такой же или мощнее — невозможно.

**UPD.** Современная наука довольно холодно относится к понятию души. Я же считаю, что она, как и разум, является сущностью иной природы, которую в физическом мире засечь очень трудно, если вообще возможно. А создать её и подавно нельзя.

В физике раньше считалось, что мир состоит только из материи и энергии. В последнее время всё больше уделяется внимания *информации* как самостоятельной сущности. У меня есть теория, что в основе бытия лежит именно информация (`В начале было Слово`, Ин.1:1), а материя и энергия — её производные. Это похоже на [цифровую физику](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), но в той считается, что мир можно вычислить битами, я же считаю, что та информация, которая определяет все законы нашего мироздания, трансцендентна, и точно не выразится байтами. То есть, мы живём в физическом мире, можем осознавать и манипулировать им, хотя мы и сам мир созданы и существуем в концепциях более высокого порядка, и ими манипулировать не можем.

Comment: Если кому-то будет интересно, могу также добавить о своём понимании души и устройства мира, хотя это отходит от темы вопроса.

Comment: Добавьте, почитаем.

Comment: @avp , дополнил.

Comment: Прочитал. А тему-то заметили и прикрыли.... (с чудовищной формулировкой)  / Я правильно понял, что Вы считаете, что и химическая (биологическая, но "из пробирки") модель не будет адекватно функционировать?

Comment: @avp да ладно уж... А что Вы думаете о моих словах? И вообще, изменилось ли у Вас мнение по вопросу за прошедшее время?

Comment: Дополнил комментарий. Нет, по сути не изменилась. Вообще-то я считаю, что просто химические основы памяти и взаимодействия поступающих сигналов с ней сейчас еще недостаточно изучены, отсюда и проблемы с нейросетями.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38859/discussion-between-aivanf-and-avp).

Answer (score 1):

Будучи агностиком, о моделировании души ничего разумного сказать не могу.

А вот, можно ли смоделировать поведение (реакции на внешние сигналы)? Думаю, что да.

В качестве доказательства можно посмотреть на недавний успех в вождении автомобиля по улицам без водителя.

В плане проявления интеллекта (точнее, сопоставления кучи известных "машине" фактов) можно вспомнить игру Watson-а в Jeopardy.

А в некоторых областях (шахматы) нечеловеческий интеллект доказал свое превосходство. Чемпионы играть с компьютерами уже перестали.

Comment: http://websum.uz/images/games/blockpawn.jpg Deep Thought в этой позиции ирал белыми и побил ладью пешкой. Это не свидетельствует о его реальном превосходстве в интеллекте! (Хоть и выигрывает гроссмейстеров)

Comment: И через сколько ходов проиграл? Но это старая программа.

Comment: тут как раз демонстрируется, что человек ПОНИМАЕТ, что не надо двигать пешки просто зная правила игры, а компьютеру надо закладывать каждый такой "казус" отдельно. Ну например заложили в программу понятие "блокирующий ряд пешек", а мы раз и подсуним вместо одной из пешек слона, у компьютера опять разрыв, а человек понимает игровую ситуацию в общем, без объяснения частных случаев. И сколько бы не закладывали в программу "казусов", нет гарантии, что перебрали все возможные. В этом различие современных компьютеров и непонятно как работающего мозга человека.

Comment: Ну потому что человек лучше всех строит модели абстракции, разбивая сложные системы на более мелкие, таким образом он теряет управление фактами низших абстракций(в отличие от компьютера который знает все факты всех абстракций) обычно содержа лишь один bool на конкретный экземпляр классов этой абстракции и указатели на связанные экземпляры, формирующие память. 

С помощью этих bool он способен быстро передвигаться по дереву логики, принимая решения, не анализируя всю связанную систему на ходу, а опираясь на предыдущие анализы.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы и нет — большущая нейронная сеть, обучающаяся многие годы, немного хаоса/случайностей, немного эха событий. Огромный объём связанной информации может, даже какую-то ненулевую добавленную массу будет иметь, и не пропадать бесследно после гибели (реинкарнироваться). Представьте, что будет, если «погибнет» интернет ; )

«Настоящность» — вопрос для философских баталий, без единственного решения.

Comment: Нейронные сети обычно заточены под обучение чего-то конкретного, а не всего, что под руку попадётся. Для того, чтобы провернуть то что вы написали необходимо внедрить ещё и что-то наподобие "Любопытства", а также научить модель каким то образом ассоциировать поток данных, как то их хранить и использовать при надобности. Если бы всё было так просто, как вы написали - она бы уже существовала, я думаю.

Comment: А как младенец «учится», и чему, собственно? Есть базовая тема собственного тела - что оно может, и что ему требуется. Ручки до макушки ещё не достают. И вообще поначалу не слушаются ) Но постепенно «сеть» узнаёт, что ими можно управлять, и начинает делать это «осознано». Т.е. идёт фаза определения оборудования : ) И есть потребности, которые если не удовлетворены — alarm! А уже потом, из этих примитивных драйверов + любопытство + внешние инициативы родителей + случайность получается настроенная сеть «личность». Упростил, да.

Comment: при попытке создать нейросеть на подобных принципах проблема именно в случайном создании комбинаций связей, в другой терминалогии - обучению алгоритму правильной реакции ИИ на заданное воздействие; так как не всякая задача "апроксимируется" по шкале "немножко правильное решение"->"совсем правильное решение", и вероятность создать правильную комбинацию связей СРАЗУ равносильно написанию стаей обезьян случайно нажимающие клавиши клавиатуры всех пьес Шекспира. Как же человеческий разум решает такие задачи сравнительно быстро?